# Load images using React/Webpack

Tags: reactjs, image, webpack

I set up the rule in `webpack` to load `png` images:

```
   {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    loaders: [
      'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
      'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
    ]
    }
```

That I found here: [cannot load png files with webpack, unexpected character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568114/cannot-load-png-files-with-webpack-unexpected-character)

`Webpack` seems to be working fine, giving no errors. So, I tried loading the png images paths that are located at `app_folder/public/images/pca` inside the `render` method:

```
  importAll = (r) => {
    return r.keys().map(r);
  }

  render() {
    const pca_images = this.importAll(require.context('../public/images/pca', 
    false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
      console.log('pca_images')
      console.log(pca_images)
...
}
```

When I launch the app I do not see any errors but the `pca_images` is an empty array. The component itself is located at `app_folder/views/`. I tried loading the images also directly like that:

```
 <img src={ require('../public/images/image1.png') } />
```

But whatever path I specify, it is just not working giving an error. I need to load all images from the folder `app_folder/public/images/pca` though, not just statically since I do not know the names of the images beforehand. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to add the rule to the `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
    test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/i,
    use: [
    {
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        limit: 10000
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This rule I found here: [ReactJS and images in public folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196800/reactjs-and-images-in-public-folder)

Then I needed to run two commands in terminal:

```
npm install url-loader --save-dev
npm install file-loader --save-dev
```

And finally loading from the folder (see the question, `render` method) started working.